# PHP Json Help need?

Tags: php, json

I need to convert the below result. I generate this JSON array using PHP but now I need the same result into a single curly brace.  Below is my PHP code to generate the JSON.

```
    $arr = array();
    #If no data was returned, check for any SQL errors 
    if ($res == false) 
    { 
       echo 'Query not Executed : '.  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
    }
    else
    {       
        while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $arr[] = array(
                'code' => array_search($obj['name'], $countries_iso), 
                'total' => $obj['Total']
                );
        }
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json");    
    #Output the JSON data 

    print (json_encode($arr));
```

### Output of above PHP code:

```
 [
  {
   code: "AF",
   total: 1
  },
  {
   code: "DZ",
   total: 1
  },
  {
   code: "AS",
   total: 2
  }
 ]
```

### But I want to show like below result:

```
 {
  "AF":1
  "DZ": 1,
  "AS": 2
 }
```

Comment: `$arr2[ array_search($obj['name'], $countries_iso) ]  = $obj['Total']`

Comment: So you gave up and none of these helped you?

Comment: **@AbraCadaver** Solve already.  the above Answer given by **@stdob--**.

Comment: That's a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want `$arr[array_search($obj['name'], $countries_iso)] = $obj['Total'];`

Your mistake was the fact that you were declaring a new array each time you add something to your original array. This way you assign the correct way :)

Try this code:

```
$arr = array();
#If no data was returned, check for any SQL errors 
if ($res == false) 
{ 
   echo 'Query not Executed : '.  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}
else
{       
    while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $arr[array_search($obj['name'], $countries_iso)] = $obj['Total'];
    }
}

header("Content-type: application/json");    
#Output the JSON data 
//$json = json_encode($arr);
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
$arr[array_search($obj['name'], $countries_iso)] = $obj['Total'];
```

But you can get rid of the whole `array_search($obj['name'], $countries_iso)` if you restrict the query to only return rows `WHERE name IN (list of $countries_iso)`.  Look up `WHERE` and `IN` for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your data structure to an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), where the value you are currently storing in `code` will be the key and the value stored in `total` will be value.

I'll be able to help better if you post the code that generates your current JSON object

Comment: @Mediasoft : check my new answer :)